# Split single dimension array into 2 arrays

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Sorry for not being so clear in advance, it is kinda hard for me to describe.
Right now I am having a bit of an issue with data management. I have thing string inside a database for graphic data.

```
f0||Title Text||f1||Subtitle Text||f2||Option 1||f3||Option 2
```

Right now, I can query the data and split the string shown above into a single dimensional array by using this "||" separator. As of right now the code is as follows.

```
MySQLHandler handler = new MySQLHandler(this.text_DataIP.Text.ToString());
        List<string>[] data = handler.SelectCG("graphics", text_CGBuffer.Text.ToString());
        string x = data[2][0].ToString();
        string[] y = x.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        // For each string in the new string array, lets separate them into their own strings for adding to the DataSet
        for (int n = 0; n < y.Length; )

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        DataTable table = dataset.Tables.Add();
        table.Columns.Add("fieldid");
        table.Columns.Add("values");
```

What is missing is the code that for every other string in the array, it will alternate in adding the data to the DataTable. For example, "f0, f1, f2, f3" will go into the column "fieldid" and the other strings will go into the values column.

I was thinking about doing a for loop but I do not know if that is the most efficient way of doing it. What would be more efficient and how would I achieve this?

Comment: Will this string have a 1-to-1 ratio of column to values? Or will there be more columns and values?

Comment: It is always going to be a 1 to 1 ratio. The reason why I am not putting up multiple columns in the database table is because the data format may change in later iterations of the software so I am future proofing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I tested with. I think it will work for you:

```
string x = "f0||Title Text||f1||Subtitle Text||f2||Option 1||f3||Option 2";
string[] y = x.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add();
List<object> rowvalues = new List<object>(); //to hold the row values

//Loop through 2 at a time,  
for (int n = 0; n < y.Length; n = n + 2) 
{
    dt.Columns.Add(y[n]); //add the column
    rowvalues.Add(y[n + 1]); //and save the value
}

//Create the row
var dr = dt.NewRow();
//Set the row values
dr.ItemArray = rowvalues.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey. What changes would need to be made to make this only use 2 columns? the "f0,f1,f2" would need to be in 1 column but pertain to the same row as the data next to it. From what I can tell, it creates a new column every time.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop would suffice. The most efficient way is to iterate the loop only once to separate the id and value.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
        {
           string fieldid = y[i];
            string value = y[++i];
        }
```